# symfony doctrine inconsistent mapping

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have this error in the symfony2 console:

```
The mappings Cpj\ProjectsBundle\Entity\Project#id_user and Cpj\UserBundle\Entity\User#projects are inconsistent with each other
```

this is my user class (I'm using fosUserBundle:

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
...
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cpj\ProjectsBundle\Entity\Project", mappedBy="user")
 **/
private $projects;
}
```

and this is my project class

```
class Project {
...
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cpj\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="projects")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $id_user;
}
```

I think I correctly followed the instructions in the symfony cookbook but I'm unable to understand what's wrong...
thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your User entity you used

```
mappedBy="user"
```

Then named the property in your Project entity

```
private $id_user;
```

You need them to match for this to work, the mappedBy annotation option refers to the property name not the database field.

This line, that defines the database field which will store the reference, can be different however

```
  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user", referencedColumnName="id")
```

Usually we use `mappedBy="user"` & `private $user` & `JoinColumn(name="id_user" [...]` for good readability both in the application and in the database. Keep in my you'll be working with entities, `$project->getUser()->getName();` is much prettier than `$project->getUserId()->getName();`. In the database on the other hand a  `id_user` field in the project table is more telling than using `user`.